# Merge different data frames for common columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 5 different data frames. I want to merge them together based on the common columns that they have. However how can I do it? I read about multimerge but I am not quite sure how to do it. For example my csv files are like

```
1st data frame df1
country  year weather temperature
```

```
2nd data frame df2
country year region
```

```
3rd data frame df3
country humidity weather year temperature region
```

```
4th data frame  df4
country region weather humidity temperature
```

Thus my final data frame should look like

```
country year region
```

(since these columns are in common)
should I use

```
total < - multimerge(df1,df2,df3,df4, by = ["country,year,region"]
```

However this throws an error.

Do you suggest another way that perhaps automatically finds the common columns and drops the rest?

Comment: try `multimerge(list(df1,df2,df3,df4), by = c("country","year","region"))`

Comment: I m sorry I am new to R. It says "could not find function "multimerge" " I found the command from here https://rdrr.io/github/vapniks/mergeutils/src/R/merge_utils.R. However it is not integrated in R? Do I have to copy paste the big code as a function? Or can insert it by installing a package?

Comment: In that case, you can use `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by=c("country","year","region")),list(df1,df2,df3,df4))`

Answer (score 0):

The `multimerge` function you refer to is from package `mergeutils`.

You can use purely base R solution like this

```r
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by=c("country","year","region")),list(df1,df2,df3,df4))
```

Comment: So I did the reduce command as you said like total<- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by=c("Country","Year")),list(df1,df2,df3)) but total returns as a dataframe with 0 obs and 36 variables

Comment: @vakalo can you check if `c("Country","Year"))` are the common field names and values/format are the same across your tables?